# Как запретить другому пользователю редактирование скрипта, но чтобы скрипт выполнялся?

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

Есть google таблица, права на редактирование даны всем. Есть скрипт myonEdit - установленный на выполнение как триггер, который отправляет e-mail при редактировании ячеек. Существует ли возможность выполнять скрипт у пользователей, обращающихся к таблице, таким образом, чтобы они не могли видеть код скрипта в редакторе скриптов?
Задача в том, чтобы скрипт выполнялся у всех редактирующих страницу, но при этом они не могли испортить/удалить/поменять код в скрипте, а для этого надо его либо скрыть, либо даже не знаю как.
Мне кажется существует способ добиться того, чего я хочу. Подскажите в какую сторону гуглить.

Comment: Пробуйте https://zapier.com/ или что-то подобное. Там можно настроить триггер на изменение чего-то.

Comment: Допустим, такое возможно. Но в чем смысл отправлять письма при редактировании ячеек? Что будет в этих письмах? В них НЕ БУДЕТ информации об авторе изменений.

Answer (score 0):

На сколько мне известно, если. вы даете доступ на редактирование таблицы, то любой редактор сможет изменить код.

Это происходит потому что скрипт встроен в контейнер (таблицу) и он наследует ее права.

---

[g-apps-script.com](https://g-apps-script.com) - русскоязычный учебник google apps script.